# Specify a function f that is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

Specify a function $f$ that is invertible but such that there is no matrix $A$ such that $f (x)=Ax$.

This problem is in "Coding the Matrix" by Philip N.Klein

I don't understand this problem. Help me please.

Comment: How about $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x) = x^3$? [edit: ninja'd by Batman himself!]

Answer (score 3):

Well, take any non-linear invertible function.

For example, if $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is given by $f(x) = x^3$, there is  no matrix $A$ which describes this transformation.